# Bokeh Button is not working in the interactive plot

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, button, plot, bokeh

So I am just trying to implement a button for my bokeh interactive plot, but no matter what I do, every time I press the button, nothing happens in the plot.  I have tried pretty much every example I saw, but nothing is working and the button has no functionality. I am very confused on why. Any tips?

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button

x = [x*0.05 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x
button = Button()
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

button.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
   var data = source.data;
   x = data['x']
   y = data['y']

   for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], 6)
   }
   
   source.change.emit();
"""))
        
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)
layout = column(button, plot)
show(layout)

#curdoc().add_root(row(button, plot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern JS requires you to declare your variables properly. Put `var` in front of the definitions of `x`, `y`, and `i`.

Comment: That was definitely it! I knew it was something minor I had missed, but I am a bit inexperienced with JS. Well this is a good motivation to get more experienced with it. Thank you very much!